Failed to build iOS app when try to build flutter Ios App
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _RT_GeoView_draw
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _RT_GeoView_hasValidSize
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _RT_GeoView_pause
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _RT_GeoView_pulse
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _RT_GeoView_resize
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _RT_GeoView_resume
Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Plus.
I have used Arcgis sdk in this flutter project and when i ma try to build ios i get error like this but android apk file successfully build . i dont get the exite error. and solution so please help me.

go to project navigator
open project file
open terminal on iOS folder
then write 'pod intsall'
then run the project from xcode

you can do clean build before running application
